# Nginx safest configuration for NodeJS app in CentOS

Tags: nginx, security, centos6, node.js

I have multiple NodeJS application running on different ports.

I needed each one of them to work through a subdomain using Nginx, for example instead of `example.com:4001` the user can work on `app1.example.com`

I found two solutions which seem to fit, however the second solution does not work yet and even if it worked I do not know if it would be more secure than the first solution or not.

Should I stick with Solution 1 or give more effort to Solution 2 ?

> Solution 1 (**Works**)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:4001";
    }
}
```

> Solution 2 (**not working yet**)
>
> `404 Not Found nginx`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.com;

    location = / {      
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

> **Operating System:** CentOS 6.9 (final)
>
> **Nginx:** 1.12.2
>
> **Custom conf file:** /etc/nginx/conf.d/nodeapps.conf

Comment: Your configuration snippet is missing `root` and `try_files` directives, therefore it cannot be answered. Anyway, most secure configuration is to run the individual application servers in separate containers / chroot jails, so that if one application has a security issue, it cannot be used to gain access to all other applications.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen any reference for your proposal ?

Comment: Not really, I haven't done any NodeJS implementations myself, only PHP-FPM. But the concept is the same anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will need one `server {}`block per subdomain as described in the documentation. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

For example

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:4001";
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:4002";
    }
}
```

I also **strongly** suggest to use the upstream module for the backends. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html